# implicit function evaluation is turned off by user

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have very simple code as below

```
DateTime? assignmentDate = new DateTime?();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objEntity_Leads.Lead_AssignedToTeleCaller))
    assignmentDate = null;
else
    assignmentDate = DateTime.ParseExact(objEntity_Leads.Lead_AssignedToTeleCaller, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In my case value of `objEntity_Leads.Lead_AssignedToTeleCaller` is `27/07/2015` but when I am inspecting these values it gives me above error.

I went through a solution as below

Tools -> Options -> Debugging and unchecked "Enable property eveluation and other function calls" but still getting same error.

What could be the solution?

Comment: Why do you store a string instead of a datetime at all?

Comment: Also, this isn't an error but an information that properties or functions which cause side effects aren't evaluated automatically by the debugger, which is a good thing. Otherwise watching the value of property `A` could change the value of property `B`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter it's a old code and I don't want to mess with those properties.

Comment: @Imad: but the question is: do you have an issue with the code, does it work as expected? Which property can't you evaluate in the debugger?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

To turn automatic property evaluation on or off

1. On the Tools menu, click Options.
2. In the Options dialog box, open the Debugging node, and click General.
3. If the Debugging node does not appear, click Show all settings.
4. Select or clear the Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls check box, and then click OK.

Comment: Yes that's worked, but i'm not sure how this got disabled automatically in VS Enterprise 15.6.4, maybe i use to take all updates in one of them they disabled it now.

Answer (score 8):

To disable "Implicit function evaluation is turned off by user", check this setting:

[image]