# Visual Studio 2022 debugger enters break state but does not recognize breakpoint being in my method used in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Community edition. I have a breakpoint set inside my method used in the Select method of LINQ. When debugging my console application debugger enters a break state but does not show that it stopped on the execution of my method. The debugger goes into break mode but displays a message

> Your app has entered a break state, but no code is currently executing that is supported by the selected debug engine (e.g. only native runtime code is executing).

Minimal reproduction code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var array = new string[] { "A X", "A Z"};
            var result = array.Select(x => Score(x)).Sum();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        public static int Score(string text)
        {
            return text.Length * 2;
        }
```

The breakpoint is set in `Score` method.

I expect that debugger would show that it stopped during the execution of my method. When I change the LINQ `Sum` method to `Count` method debugging worked correctly and recognized that breakpoint was in my method.

[Expected debugger behavior result with method changed to Count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aasut.png)

I think that it is some code optimization issue. I tried the following solutions from the internet and they did not help:

- Disabling code optimization in *Project -> right click -> Properties -> Build -> General -> Optimize Code*
- Disabling "Enable Just My Code" in *Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable Just My Code*

Does anybody know how I can fix such debugger behavior?

Comment: Try this `var result = array.Select(x => Score(x)).ToList().Sum();` and read about `IEnumerable` and when it evaluates.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy your suggestion works but I think that it is weird that I have to change the code so the debugger can work properly. I know that IEnunumeralbe does not evaluate instantly but it should evaluate when I want to print the result. Why debugger can't detect my method then

Comment: I describe you why it works so specifically. Check your vstudio settings (Implicit function calls) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164490/implicit-function-evaluation-is-turned-off-by-user

Comment: @kojon1464 Does the Roman Ryzhiy's method and link can help you solve the problem. Or do you have any other problems? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help in here.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT adding ToList() helped (Applying setting from link change did not change anything). If there is something that would work without changing the code then it would be great. But I assume there is no such easy answer. Tanks for asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this code in .net framework 4.7 project it works well. But have this problem in .net 7.

It seems no setting to fix this problem in my test. And the definition of Method Sum in [.net framework 4.7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.7) looks same as it in [.net 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-7.0).

I'm not sure if it's a problem caused by upgrading from .net framework to .net.

As Roman Ryzhiy said, you can temporarily fix this by adding .ToList() or .ToArray() to your code. And then you can report this problem on [dc](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report).